# order by date in union query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT case_id,diagnosis_title,updated 
    FROM tbl_case 
    order by updated desc 
) as table1

UNION

select * 
FROM 
(
    select image_id,image_title,updated 
    from tbl_image 
    order by updated desc 
) as table2
```

how to display records with mixed order. currently `tbl_Case` records displaying first and `tbl_image` record displaying in second section.

i want to mix the output.  `ORDER BY` should work for both table.

Answer (score 6):

Any reason you're doing those outer select *? They're rather pointless,  since they just reselect everything you've already selected.

With mysql unions, this is how you order the entire result set:

```
(SELECT case_id, diagnosis_title, ... FROM ...)
UNION
(SELECT image_id, image_title, ... FROM ...)
ORDER BY ...
```

With the bracketing in place as it is above, the order by will sort all the records from both results sets together, instead of sorting each individual query's results separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try to simply your query.

```
    SELECT case_id,diagnosis_title,updated
    FROM tbl_case 
    UNION
    select image_id,image_title,updated
    from tbl_image 
    ORDER BY updated desc
```

Comment: is it possible to add limit for each select

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, (I'm just guessing about data types)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable
    (id int, title varchar(100), updated tinyint(1));

INSERT TempTable
SELECT case_id, diagnosis_title, updated  FROM tbl_case ORDER BY updated DESC;
INSERT TempTable
SELECT image_id, image_title, updated FROM tbl_image ORDER BY updated DESC;

SELECT * FROM TempTable;
```

Obviously, this uses a temporary table instead of a union to achieve what I think you are asking for.